# Overriding static methods in PHP

Tags: php, static, overriding

I have an abstract page class looking like this:

```
abstract class Page {
    public static function display() {
        self::displayHeader();
        self::displayContent();
        self::displayFooter();
    }

    public static function displayContent() {
        print "<p>some content</p>";
    }

    public static function displayHeader() {
        include_once(kContent . "HeaderContent.class.php");
        HeaderContent::display();
    }

    public static function displayFooter() {
        include_once(kContent . "FooterContent.class.php");
        FooterContent::display();
    }
};
```

I would like to subclass from this, and only override the displayContent method, so the header and footer is being displayed automatically, but still having the option to override the display method, for example for .js files.

Now I have another class, looking like this:

```
class FooPage extends Page {
    public static function displayContent() {
        print "<p>Foo page</p>";    
};
```

Now, instead of calling the FooPage's `displayContent` method, it just calls the one from the superclass.

Why? What can I do?

**EDIT**

I'm running PHP 5.2.17

Comment: Use `static` instead of `self`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [when using self, parent, static and how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504129/when-using-self-parent-static-and-how)

Comment: not a duplicate, didn't work for me.

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of [Static Inheritance prior to PHP 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581435/static-inheritance-prior-to-php-5-3?lq=1). Why are you still on 5.2?

Comment: It's similar, but how should I call a static method, using the ReflectionClass?

Comment: Maybe your page shouldn't be a static class :)

Comment: The page class isn't static. Just the method display is static.

Also, I can't make an instance of the ReflectionClass, because display() is static.

Comment: Look at the second answer in that thread. Late static binding is simply not really possible in PHP 5.2. That's why they added it to the language in 5.3.

Comment: I understand that. My question was, how can I do a workaround using this ReflectionClass, when I don't have a $this keyword, and I want to call a static method

Comment: Why is the `display()` method static? Don't do it, if you already have an object. And then inheritance works with `$this`.

Comment: I don't have an object, I don't want to make an object if I just call this one method anyway

Comment: Then you don't get inheritance in return. :) `B::foo()` will pass through to `A:foo()` due to static binding and it will look to `A::foo()` as if it was called directly. Nothing really you can do about it.

Comment: Nice! :)
I guess I'm gonna have to override the display() method until I upgrade to PHP 5.3

Comment: @Ilija Tovilo : Why don't you want to make an object ? It will be way easier to test, to code, more powerful, and the memory cost is trivial - or even 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ilija, PHP < 5.3 doesn't have "[Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)" and that's why you may be experiencing the `FooPage::displayContent` not being called. If you are running PHP 5.2 then there is nothing much to do (except for [some hacks using debug_backtrace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#101077), which honestly I wouldn't recommend for this situation).

Now, what it really calls my attention is that your methods are all static; is there a reason for this? Why aren't they instance methods? I would expect something like:

```
include_once(kContent . "HeaderContent.class.php");
include_once(kContent . "HeaderContent.class.php");

abstract class Page 
{
    protected $header;
    protected $footer;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->header = new HeaderContent();
        $this->footer = new FooterContent();
    }

    public function display() 
    {
        $this->displayHeader();
        $this->displayContent();
        $this->displayFooter();
    }

    public function displayContent() 
    {
        print "<p>some content</p>";
    }

    public function displayHeader() 
    {
        $this->header->display();
    }

    public function displayFooter() 
    {
        $this->footer->display();
    }
};

class FooPage extends Page 
{
    public function displayContent() 
    {
        print "<p>Foo page</p>";
    }
}
```

and later in your view you would write something like:

```
$page = new FooPage();
$page->display();
```

Some things to take into account:

- It is generally better not to use print/echo when generating a view content. Instead try to create the string and do the print/echo as a last step. This makes it easier to later write tests.

Example:

```
public function display() 
{
    return 
           $this->displayHeader() . 
           $this->displayContent() . 
           $this->displayFooter();
}

public function displayContent() 
{
    return "<p>some content</p>";
}

public function displayHeader() 
{
    return $this->header->display();
}
....
$page = new FooPage();
echo $page->display();
```

- If you need to do it as your application grows, you can pass the header and footer as Page constructor parameters. As long as they are objects that understand the display() message (i.e. [polymorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)) things should be ok.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Ok, it worked with non-static methods.
What I do with printing out is following:
ob_start();
$this->output = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();
Is this too dirty?

Comment: This was meant, so I can print stuff out by closing the php tags, inserting my html code, and opening the php tags again. So I get syntax highlighting.

Comment: Well, that's a most of all a matter of taste and each person's view on "elegant" coding. I prefer leaving  the ob_start(); mechanism for times when it is the only choice. From my POV returning a string is a more elegant approach, at the cost of loosing syntax highlighting. As many other things is programming there is always a trade-off and you should choose the one that fits best your needs. However, if you go with the ob_start() approach I would advise to create a "output grabber" object that encapsulates that in a method, so that you don't repeat the ob_* process N times.

Answer (score 0):

Returned back to this question. Was looking for solution for **Symfony** **(5.4)**.
And I finally came with this "*Service - method call*" solution.

```
#services_dev.yaml:
Company\Core\PinGenerator\PinGenerator:
    calls:
        - [setDebugMode, [true]]
```

---

```
#PinGenerator:
class PinGenerator implements PinGeneratorInterface
{

    public static bool $inDebugMode = false;

    public static function setDebugMode(bool $inDebugMode): void
    {
        self::$inDebugMode = $inDebugMode;
    }

    public static function generate(int $length = self::DEFAULT_PIN_CODE_LENGTH, bool $numbersOnly = true): string
    {
        if (!self::$inDebugMode) {
            return PinGeneratorProd::generate($length, $numbersOnly);
        } else {
            return PinGeneratorDev::generate($length, $numbersOnly);
        }
    }
}
```

Honesly hoping, that this will help someone, someday.