# self::method() call uses parent method instead of called class

Tags: php

I have two classes:

```
class JController{
   public static function getInstance()
   {
       //some source, not important...
       self::createFile();// 
   }

   public static function createFile()
   {
       // this is base class method
   }
}

class CustomController extends JController{

   public static function createFile()
   {
       // this is overriden class method
   }
}
```

And I am trying to call static method on derived class which calls parents method and not overriden. Is it expected behaviour?

That's how I try to use it:

```
$controllerInstance = CustomController::getInstance();
```

My question is: why doesn't CustomController::getInstance() call on CustomController::createFile()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding static methods in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174343/overriding-static-methods-in-php)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate, didn't found it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is expected behavior. Before php 5.3 static methods will only call the method from the first definition in the hierarchy. 5.3+ has [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) support and with that the ability to use the method directly on the child class. To do this you need to use the `static` keyword instead of `self`:

```
   public static function getInstance()
   {
       //some source, not important...
       static::createFile();// 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe there other way around it? Because class I am overriding is Joomla's, by the way your answer was first and I will accept in couple of minutes

Comment: Not that i can think of without modifying a core class. That said depending upon the logic of createFile, and exactly what you want the end result to be there might be another way.

Comment: I only needed to call my static method instead of one from the base class, so I have copied source of that method and changed `self` to `static` and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

[Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

use

```
static::createFile();
```

instead of

```
self::createFile();
```